# Promise Chaining error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am learning how to use Promise without libraries. From what I have read, I could chain Promise together and then add `.catch` in the end for error handling.

**What do I expect**

So if I change the URL to some false url, shouldn't I be catching the error and stop the entire program to be continuing?

**What Am I seeing now?**

When I put a false url, the program just throws out an error, instead of handling it like an rejection.

```
const request = require("request");

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=321%20i%20st%20davis",
    (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        reject("bad call on geo code!");
      }
      resolve(JSON.parse(body).results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  );
})
  .then(res => {
    const {lat, lng} = res;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(
        `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/6fb416a8313aabd902a22558e07cc032/${lat},${lng}`,
        (err, res, body) => {
          if (err) {
            reject("bad call on darksky");
          }
          resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        }
      );
    });
  })
  .then(res => {
    const currentTemp = res.currently.temperature;
    const feelTemp = res.currently.apparentTemperature;
    const temps = {currentTemp, feelTemp};
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(
        "http://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes",
        (err, res, body) => {
          if (err) {
            reject("bad call on quotes");
          }
          resolve({temps, body});
        }
      );
    });
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(
      `Today's weather is ${res.temps.currentTemp}, and it feels like ${res
        .temps
        .feelTemp}! \nAnd here is your stupid quote of the day: \n${JSON.parse(
        res.body
      )[0]}`
    );
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Error Message:

This isn't really meaningful, basically the error did not stop the program, which just passed down to the next promise. That promise receive the error but could not parse it because it is not in expected JSON format.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Promise.then.then.then.res (/Users/leoqiu/reacto/playground/6_promiseMethod.js:48:74)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it depends on which stage do i change the url, so basically reject throw out the error, and that error message was passed down which is handled by `res` for the next Promise. So the error is just a JSON parsing error.

Comment: Also added the error in

Comment: You aren't leaving after executing `reject()`, eg doing a `return`, in your if statement. So your code continues on to try to do the `resolve()` which tries to do `JSON.parse`, which if you used a fake url is going to cause an error because body is undefined or null

Comment: so wouldn't `reject` stop it going further?

Comment: `reject()` doesn't stop the current block of code from executing

Comment: interesting, so i need to add a `throw` in each if statement then.

Comment: No, you simply need to do a `return` after your reject() call. Also note that your catch() callback is working as it is printing out the caught error message, it just printed out the error you weren't expecting.

Comment: just an FYI on making coding with promises easier to use. You have 3 calls to `request` that you've individually "promisified", which is great, because they all do slightly different things with the result. However, you can make the process easier on yourself by creating a "promisified" `request` function ... see how simple your code can get [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y8t974d/)

Comment: @JaromandaX That is great! Thanks for making my code cleaner!

Comment: there's a slight error in it though, `.then(({currently:{currentTemp, feelTemp}}) =>` should be `.then(({currently:{temperature:currentTemp, apparentTemperature:feelTemp}}) =>` ... and, of course, you could just add `request-promise` library (or `request-promise-native` ) and not bother promisifying request so "basically" like in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `reject()` inside your `if` statement, you don't return and you don't use an `else` so your `resolve(JSON.parse(body).results[0].geometry.location);` still gets executed and that throws an exception.

You can change to this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=321%20i%20st%20davis",
    (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        reject("bad call on geo code!");
        return;
      }
      resolve(JSON.parse(body).results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  );
})
```

It is a common mistake that people think `reject()` works like `break` or some other control flow statement because `reject()` is a type of promise control flow.  But, it doesn't stop execution in your block so you need to either `return` after it or use an `else`.

Or, I prefer to use `if/else` because I think it makes the logic even more obvious:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request(
    "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=321%20i%20st%20davis",
    (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        reject("bad call on geo code!");
      } else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body).results[0].geometry.location);
      }
    }
  );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Patrick Evans suggestion...

`reject` does not stops the program from running, so the error message gets pass down to the next Promise, which is why is throwing a `json` parsing error.

The solution is simply put a `return` in the rejection.

```
if (err) {
    reject("bad call on geo code!");
    return err;
  }
```